# If two power series are equal on an interval, does that imply that their coefficients must be equal?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

$$f_1(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots$$

$$f_2(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \ldots$$

$$f_1(x) = f_2(x) \ \ \ \forall x \in \left(-\frac 1 2 , \frac 1 2 \right)$$

I found $a_i$ and $b_i$ via Taylor expansion, there are an infinite amount of non-zero coefficients.

I am quite sure that this implies that $a_i = b_i \ \ \forall i$, because all $i$'th derivatives need to be equal. This is not a mathematically rigorous proof, though. How can I rigorously prove this?

Comment: Hint: Take the difference of the polynomials. This is again a polynomial.

Comment: @Maurits van Altvorst Are you taking polynomials or power series? If it is polynomial then I do not see any harm in taking derivatives.

Comment: And combine that with the fundamental theorem of algebra? I was not sure whether that applied because of the small interval

Comment: I found $a_i$ and $b_i$ via Taylor expansion, therefore there are an infinite amount of $a_i$ and $b_i$. I think that implies that I cannot use the question you linked, Martin.

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst If there is an infinite amount of $a_i$, then the two functions are not polynomials

Comment: @5xum you are right! I've edited my question.

Comment: To be rigorous we should add the hypothesis "on an open non-empty interval", to avoid pathological cases such as an empty or singleton interval (and so there is no difficulty talking about derivatives in the proof, since every point has an open neighbourhood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea can easily be modified to be a formal proof.

Your assumptions mean that both functions are analytical at $0$, which means that

$$a_i = i!\cdot  \left(\frac{d^if_1}{dx^i}\right)(0)$$

while

$$b_i = i!\cdot \left(\frac{d^if_2}{dx^i}\right)(0)$$

Since the two functions are identical, you also know their derivatives are also identical, which means that

$$\left(\frac{d^if_1}{dx^i}\right)(0)=\left(\frac{d^if_2}{dx^i}\right)(0)$$

and this allows you to conclude that $a_i=b_i$.

---

Alternatively, you could note that the function $g(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ is also an analytical function. Also, on $\left(-\frac12, \frac12\right)$, you have $g(x)=0$. Therefore, you have, on the interval:

$$0=g(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i - \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty(a_i-b_i)x^i$$

and therefore, $a_i-b_i=0$ for all $i$ (because if some $a_i\neq b_i$, then the sum on the right will not equal the sum on the left. You can prove this by taking the $i$-th derivative of the RHS).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Just to clarify, because my functions take on the same values on interval $(-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$, that means that all i'th derivatives to infinity are also equal? This makes sense intuitively, but there is no more rigorous proof required to make this statement?

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst If you narrow the two functions down to the interval $I=\left(\frac12, \frac12\right)$, then what you are left with is not two functions, but one. I.e., all their properties, when narrowed down, are the same. In other words, the set $\{f_1|_I, f_2|_I\}$ is a singleton. They cannot at the same time be the same function and differ in some property.

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst But if you want, you can also convince yourself by going over the definition of the derivative. For $x\in I$, you have $$f_1'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_1(x+h)-f_1(x)}{h}.$$ Now, you know that if $h$ is small enough, then $x+h\in I$, which means that $$\frac{f_1(x+h)-f_1(x)}{h} = \frac{f_2(x+h)-f_2(x)}{h}$$ which means
$$f_1'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_1(x+h)-f_1(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_2(x+h)-f_2(x)}{h} = f_2'(x)$$

So, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ match on $I$, then $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ match on $I$. Inductively, you can conclude this is the same with higher order derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation!